# Magento 2 sucess/faliure message displaying + concatenated string.

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

Hello I am new to Magento (Magento 2.1) My problem is that when any message like sign up successfully or order successfully it is displayed word joining with + sign instead of space. like : 
[image]

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the code where you concatenate the message. The message should be

```
$this->messageManager->addError( __('This is your error message.') );
//or
$this->messageManager->addError( __('Invalid %s or %s', 'login', 'password') );
//or replace with variables
```